# Building a string with only two repeating characters

Tags: c#

The below is the C# implementation for the a function for given parameters `int a`, `int b` - both represent characters 'A' and 'B' respectively, where the function should return a string containing both characters 'A' and 'B' occurring `a` times and `b` times respectively but neither 'A' nor 'B' repeating consecutively for more than 2 times. Both values for `a` and `b` are given in a way that a string can be build using those numbers - so eg: `Foo(0,3)` or `Foo(1,7)` shall not be invoked.

eg:

`Foo(3,3)` returns "`BBAABA`" or "`AABBAB`"

`Foo(4,1)` returns "`AABAA`"

`Foo(3,5)` returns "`BAABBABB`" or "`BBAABBAB`"

Code:

```
static string Foo(int a, int b)
{
    int total = a + b;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    char charToPrint = a > b ? 'A' : 'B';
    int flag = 0;

    for(int x =0; x< total; x++)
    {
        if(flag == 2)
        {
            flag = 0;
            charToPrint = SwapChar(charToPrint);
        }
        if(charToPrint == 'A' && a == 0 || charToPrint == 'B' && b == 0)
        {
            charToPrint = SwapChar(charToPrint);
        }

        if (charToPrint == 'A')
            a--;
        else
            b--;

        sb.Append(charToPrint);
        flag++;
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}

static char SwapChar(char thisChar)
{
    return thisChar == 'A' ? 'B' : 'A';
}
```

This is working but I would like to receive some feedback on this code.

Comment: It looks like you've forgotten to include your `SwapChar` method. What is the code supposed to do when it is impossible to create a string with the  requirements? E.g. `Foo(0, 3)` is impossible but your code returns `"BBB"` which violates the last rule.

Comment: @RobH added the `SwapChar` method. Btw, I just edited the question to include the `Foo(0,3)` shall be called.

Answer (score 9):

Your algorithm has a flaw - it's too greedy. Take this example:

```
Foo(6, 2) // "AABBAAAA"
```

Alas, it should return "AABAABAA".

In terms of a review, your method shouldn't be called `Foo` - give it a descriptive name.

Great use of `StringBuilder`. You could initialize the length to a+b in the constructor as you know what size your finished string will be.

Expression bodied members can greatly improve readability in my opinion:

```
static char SwapChar(char c) => 
    c == 'A' ? 'B' : 'A';
```

Try to avoid variables like `flag`. I had to read the whole loop before I knew what that variable meant. I'd call it something like `repeatCount`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and indicating the flaw